# SharePoint Hosted Add-in asking for credential

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

My scenario : I have created a SharePoint 2016 farm and created a simple hello world SharePoint hosted add-in. I have successfully deployed the add-in via visual studio in one of the site. When i click on the add-in thought, it is asking for credential, i have used the same window login i have used to deploy the add-in but it shows me just a white screen in the end.

Note: i have even added the App domain as an intranet site for Internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable loopback check, I faced same case early, after disable loopback check, works fine.

https://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/sharepoint-add-in-in-sharepoint-2016-on-premise